# What is the difference between 'sometime' and 'sometimes'?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

I wrote an erroneous sentence recently. My teacher corrected it.
Here is the sentence.

Thus, the driver experiences a poor vision while driving, or sometime a faulty vision due to reflection of water droplets.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the experiencing of *a poor vision*. Maybe he or she should change religions?

Comment: You may be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is Off Topic General Reference for ELU (but it might be okay on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/))

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, just look at the spelling: 
*sometime* is *some* + **time** (singular, also spelled two words, **some time** ) while *sometimes* is *some* + **times** (plural, one word). Some examples:

*Let's get together sometime for dinner.* 
( **time** has no 's', which means it refers to an indefinite day, usually in the future)

*We sometimes get together for dinner.* 
(**times** has the plural 's', meaning we have had dinner together at least twice, and the tense of **get** implies that it may happen again. The plural spelling plus the verb form both show a repetition of the action.)

Your teacher corrected your sentence to **sometimes** (overlooking "a poor vision"!) for the simple reason that you were talking about past, present, and future time.

Some people claim that *sometime* is not a word, but there is an obvious difference in meaning and pronunciation between *some time* and *sometime*.  For example:

*Stop by and see me **sometime** when you have some **time**.*

Answer (score -2):

Sometime is not a word. Sometimes (meaning 'on occasion') is, and is what you meant to write. Some time (meaning 'at an unspecified [specific] time') means something different.

Comment: Perhaps you should go up and tell Mae West that sometime.